# Arrays in Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: mergesort

im trying to understand Merge Sort Algorithm working, im having issues that i don't understand where all the data members were stored when two created arrays sorting operations are performed?

Answer (score 0):

i have understood now Merge sort doesn't create new arrays, it just create logical arrays and performs all the operations on the original array, this article will clear your concepts about [merge sort c++](http://www.hellgeeks.com/merge-sort/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see following link for your solution.

http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Merge/Sorted_arrays

```
          // size of C array must be equal or greater than

           // sum of A and B arrays' sizes

     public void merge(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {

          int i, j, k, m, n;
          i = 0;
          j = 0;
          k = 0;
          m = A.length;
          n = B.length;
          while (i < m && j < n) {
                if (A[i] <= B[j]) {
                      C[k] = A[i];
                      i++;
                } else {
                      C[k] = B[j];
                     j++;
                }
               k++;
          }
          if (i < m) {
                for (int p = i; p < m; p++) {
                      C[k] = A[p];
                     k++;
                }
          } else {
                for (int p = j; p < n; p++) {
                      C[k] = B[p];
                     k++;
                }
          }
    }
```